# Best data structure for nested multi tenant structure

Tags: javascript, json, multi-tenant

I am not sure if I am going the right way about structuring my data, I am looking at creating a multi tenant database which I will provide as JSON to the front end with the relevant information for each client.

Below is an example array with one entry that represents one clients data, this would be repeated for each client.

Each client will have subsets of client data which include employees, teams, locations etc.

Each client will have an array of customers who will all be able to be assigned rewards, and enter personal info which will be accessible by the client, the same applies for all the other nested arrays and objects.

Is this nested way of structuring things the correct way to go, or should I have a seperate structure for clients and customers.

````
[
  {
    client_id: 12345678,
    client_name: "client one",
    client_email: "email@email.com",
    client_teams: [
      {
        team_id: 1234,
        team_name: "team one",
        team_location_id: "ldn_01"
      },
      {
        team_id: 1234,
        team_name: "team two",
        team_location: "ldn_02"
      }
    ],
    client_employees: [
      {
        employee_id: 1234,
        team_id: 1234,
        employee_email: "email@email.com",
        employee_password: "password",
        employee_username: "name",
        employee_access: "admin"
      },
      {
        employee_id: 4567,
        team_id: 1234,
        employee_email: "email@email.com",
        employee_password: "password",
        employee_username: "name",
        employee_access: "viewer"
      }
    ],
    is_connected: false,
    date_joined: "date",
    customers: [
      {
        customer_id: 1234,
        first_name: "firstname",
        last_name: "last name",
        date_joined: "date",
        total_rewards_redeemed: 1,
        total_points_accumulated: 20,
        current_points_accumulated: 2,
        rewards_available: [1234, 1235],
        age: 25,
        city: "London"
      }
    ],
    locations: [
      { location_id: 1234, location_name: "location one" },
      { location_id: 2234, location_name: "location two" }
    ],
    rewards: [
      {
        reward_id: 1234,
        reward_name: "10off",
        reward_description: "10% off",
        reward_start_date: "25-06-2022",
        reward_end_date: "30-06-2023"
      }
    ],
    campaigns: []
  }
];```
````

Comment: The structure of your API response has nothing to do with the database being mult-tenant or not. You just have to ensure that you query all data from a single tenant only, not accidentally returning data from multiple tenants at once.

Comment: Does "client" mean the same as "tenant" to you? Or will you have multiple clients per tenant?

Comment: "*should I have a seperate structure for clients and customers?*" - this is basic ER modeling. Do you have customers that are shared by a single client?